# how to find out the SCL for a message which has been delivered to a mailbox in exchange 2010?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

How would one go about finding the SCL associated with a incoming e-mail into an Exchange 2010 machine? We're using the anti-spam tools built into Exchange but would like to see what SCL messages have been awarded to see how to improve things as a few messages are slipping through the filters.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Couple options for you - should still work with whatever version of Outlook you're on.

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/895091
- http://www.petri.co.il/display_scl_level_in_outlook_2003.htm

Answer (score 1):

A universal way to find it out (regardless of client) is to just to look in the message headers for "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL" :)